# Geometry nodes instance rotation and scale

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object

I have a simple text node setup:

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to set the rotation and scaling of each instance so that I can scale/rotate each letter? Either by randomly setting the scaling and rotation values or by setting them manually?

Comment: There are already some questions (and answers) here that deal with this topic, but try to use the node `Random Value` in the input *Rotation* and *Scale*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in this case the individual letters exist as instances, you have already made the right choice with `Rotate Instances` and `Scale Instances`.

These nodes treat each instance as an independent object and rotate and scale them according to the given values.

For your values you use in this case the node `Random Value`, which creates a new value per instance.

The rotation per instance around a certain axis can be refined with the node `Rotate Euler`. This will then rotate each instance in a certain range around a certain axis.

When scaling, however, you can directly use the float output of the node `Random Value` in the input *Scale*, whereby you force the same value for each axis (conversion from float to vector).

[image]